# METEOR: How to implement fallback if asset come with 404 not found? HTTP get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm using `meteor-upload` to upload user file. So far working as expected. I store uploaded file name into collection like this pattern:

```
"profile" : {
        "avatar" : "/upload/some_random_id.jpg"
}
```

In case, some unexpected issue happen (app crash or update or something which will destroy local asset), I backup upload folder into different server. Just called `http://backupsite.com`.

How to implement fallback if local asset come with 404 not found? What I can think is to use conditional statement like this:

```
{{#if profile.avatar loaded}}
    <img src="{{this}}">
{{else}}
    <img src="http://backupsite.com{{this}}">
{{/if}}
```

Now is helper. How to check whether `profile.avatar` is loaded or not? HTTP get?

thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Saves only the file name in your db

```
"profile" : {
    "avatar" : "some_random_id.jpg"}
```

and check startup upload

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/tmp',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/.uploads/',
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    overwrite: true
});
```

and use:

```
<img src="http:/upload/{{this}}">
```